# Como comparar cadenas en ficheros

Tags: c++11

Quisiera saber como comparar cadenas en ficheros ver si existe el dato que se va ingresando por teclado.

#### Codigo

```
void agregar (){
            system ("cls");
    cout<<"ingrese el carnet del alumno"<<endl;
    cin>>carnet;
    cout<<"ingrese el nombre del alumno"<<endl;
    cin>>nombre;
    cout<<"ingrese el apellido del alumno"<<endl;
    cin>>apellidos;
    cout<<"ingrese el telefono del alumno"<<endl;
    cin>>telefono;
    cout<<"ingrese el correo del alumno"<<endl;
    cin>>correo;
    ofstream alum;
    alum.open("alumnos.txt",ios::app);
        alum<<carnet<<endl;
        alum<<nombre<<endl;
        alum<<apellidos<<endl;
        alum<<telefono<<endl;
        alum<<correo<<endl;
    //  char tem[10];
    //  char carnet[10];
    //if (strcmp(!tem,carnet)==0){
                //  cout<<"esta registrado"<<endl;
            //  }
            //  else{
            //      cout<<"ingrese otro numero de carnet"<<endl;
            //      cin>>alu.carnet;
            //      alum<<alu.carnet<<endl;

    //}
    alum.close();
    }
```

Comment: Debes tener una lista de esos datos, al agregar un aluno debes ser agregado tan como en tu lista como en tu fichero, y al iniciar el programa simplemente recorres tu fichero y guardas esos datos en tu lista. Es la solucion mas facil y q la mayoria utiizarian

Comment: Un fichero no contiene cadenas sino que es un flujo de bytes... el sentido a esos bytes se lo da la aplicación cuando lee el fichero. Deberás leer el fichero registro a registro y, en cada iteración, comparar el carnet del registro que has leido con el que te facilita el usuario.

Comment: esque al momento que yo agrego una variable temporal para compararlo con el carnet no me dice que esta registrado el mismo numero de carnet